# Next.js Link error when try to put FontAwesome in the body

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, font-awesome

I use [react-fontawesome](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/react-fontawesome) library in my `Next.js` project. When I try to put any icon inside the `Link` component there is an error and I don't understand it at all. Can someone explain me why I can't do that? Besides that error, app works fine - it redirects to correct page.

Error (shows **only** in browser console - there is nothing in terminal about it):
[[image]]

Code:

```js
import Link from 'next/link'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faHeart } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons'

const Component = () => {
    return (
        // ...
        <Link href='/followed'>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHeart} />
        </Link>
        // ...
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the [official documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#if-the-child-is-a-function-component), you should `forwardRef` to the child if it is a functional component (`FontAwesomeIcon` here). Meaning, functional components by default do not accept `ref` prop passed by the `Link` component. This is not required if the `Link` component wraps native elements (e.g `div`,`a`) , but since you are using a functional component (either from a third-party library or self-written), it is required to `forwardRef` the component as the error states.

```
import Link from 'next/link'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faHeart } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons'
import React from 'react'
const Component = () => {
    const MyLinkComponent = React.forwardRef(({ onClick, href }, ref) => {
    return (
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHeart} />
    )
    })
    return (
        // ...
        <Link href='/followed' passHref>
            <MyLinkComponent/>
        </Link>
        // ...
    )
}
```

Also note that, I've used `passHref` prop in the `Link` component that forces `Link` to send the `href` property to its child. Default value is `false`.

Comment: But you are not using any of `ref` to **FontAwesomeIcon** !

Comment: Yes, FontAwesomeIcon, here is a component that primarily doesn't act as an `a` tag or any native element, and also they don't accept any `ref` prop. Hence, we're using `forwardRef` only to suppress the error as stated in itself.

Answer (score 1):

`Link` Component pass attributes that `FontAwesomeIcon` don't accept, You need to wrap the `FontAwesomeIcon` on native html element in this case like `span`

```
import Link from 'next/link'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faHeart } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons'



    const Component = () => {
        return (
            // ...
            <Link href='/followed'>
                <span><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHeart} /></span>
            </Link>
            // ...
        )
    }
```